# C: While Loop With Logical OR

Tags: c

I am writing a simple text game in C where the player combats a very simple AI. Inside the main() function, there is a loop that should continue as long as the player's HP ***or*** the enemy's HP is higher than 0. See the example below.

```
while(grunt->hp > 0 || player->hp > 0) {
    stats(player);
    printf("Grunt HP: %d\n", grunt->hp);
    plyMove(player, grunt);
    aiMove(player, grunt);
}

if(player->hp > 0) {
    printf("You won the battle!\n"); }
else {
    printf("You've lost the battle!\n"); }

return 0;
```

Now to my understanding, this while loop should do it's thing as long as both expressions are true. If just one of them becomes false, the loop should end. However, if the enemy's HP is lower than zero, it will not break out. But if the player's HP is lower than zero, it breaks.

Every iteration of the loop is printing these values, so I can keep track of them.

Am I simply not understanding the logic of this? If you need to see any additional code, please let me know.

Comment: "there is a loop that should continue as long as the player's HP ***or*** the enemy's HP is higher than 0" - So you want to continue the loop until both sides die? That doesn't sound right. Are you sure you understand what "or" means?

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. In the first paragraph you acknowledge that the loop continues as long as one of the conditions is true. In the second paragraph, you say you expect the loop to stop as soon as one of the conditions is false.

Comment: I think your code is correct, it matches with your description in the first paragraph. It's the second paragraph which contradicts your first though.

Comment: just add `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a logical OR, which is true if at least one parameter is true. In other words, the truth table is this:

```
In | In | Out
T  | T  | T
T  | F  | T
F  | T  | T
F  | F  | F
```

It sounds like you want a logical AND, which is true if both parameters are true. This way, the fight continues as long as both the player and enemy have over 0 health. The operator for logical AND in C (and many other languages) is `&&`.

In case you're interested, here's the truth table for AND:

```
In | In | Out
T  | T  | T
T  | F  | F
F  | T  | F
F  | F  | F
```

Answer (score 1):

While both the grunt's hp **and** the player's hp (true) are above 0 you want the loop to continue so you want:

```
while(grunt->hp > 0 && player->hp > 0)
```

If either the grunt's hp **or** the player's hp goes below 0 the condition above will be false and you will exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If in your head you were thinking "I want to end the game when the player's HP or the enemy's HP is below or equal to zero", the right while condition would be:

```
while(!(grunt->hp <= 0 || player->hp <= 0))
```

With the logical inverse operator `!`

Recall: `!(A || B) == !A && !B` so other guys answer is strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an abstraction can make things easier to grasp.

Consider if you had:

```
#define Alive(who) ((who)->hp > 0)
```

then you could write:

```
while (Alive(grunt) && Alive(player)) {
    …
}
```